# Not getting downloaded apk file in Emulator

Tags: android

I have downloaded an apk file from one site in the emulator its show getting downloaded at the top of the screen in an arrow button.but i didn't find the apk file in my SD card or anyvery else.Will it be stored in any other location in the emuliator.

Will any one help me to find the downloaded apk file place in emuliator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The downloaded file is supposed to be stored in a "download" folder on the sdcard. Check `mnt/sdcard/download` folder, the apk might be there (Use the DDMS to do so).

Comment: In the DDMS it shows but i need to get install this apk file.I didnt find this any where in the emultion for installing.

Comment: if it is at the same location, then install it from your command line: `adb install /sdcard/download/(your downloaded apk name)`. I don't think there might be a possibility to install the apk by any other means.

Comment: You can also check the browser's download screen, where you'll find the recent downloads on the device, and consequently your downloaded apk. Clicking on the respective download will directly initialize the installation.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your command line and to the Android-sdk-windows\platform-tools folder.
Then call:

```
adb shell
cd /sdcard/download
```

You'll see your file there.